# If $G$ is a free abelian group on a set with $n$ elements prove that $G$ cannot be generated by fewer than $n$ elements.

Tags: group-theory

This has already been asked elsewhere in the site but I want to use different methods.

> If $G$ is a free abelian group on a set with $n$ elements prove that $G$ cannot be generated by fewer than $n$ elements.

Let $G$ free abelian on $X$, $|X|=n$, $Y\subseteq G, |Y|<n$ (1).

Let $H=\langle Y\rangle$ and $F$ the free abelian group on $Y$. Then $F=\langle Y\rangle, F=H, H$ free abelian on $Y$. If $G=H, G\cong H$ and $|X|=|Y|$ contradicting (1). So $H<G$.

I have restricted myself to using the theorems appearing (in the book I'm reading) before this problem, but I suspect of this because it is too simple. Instead I could use results in the section where the problem is: keeping the notation above, as $H$ is finitely generated (f.g.) I have it is the direct sum of say, $r$ infinite cyclic groups and $s$ cyclic groups of prime-power orders. But $G$ is the direct sum of $n$ infinite cyclic groups and so f.g.

Assume $G=H$. Then by the uniqueness of such decompositions for f.g. groups, $r=n$ and $s=0$. What I get is that a direct sum of $n$ subgroups of $G$ is being generated by a set of less elements than $n$:

$$C_1\oplus ... \oplus C_n=H=\langle Y\rangle$$ (2) with $|Y|<n$.

And now, to show there is a contradiction on the assumption $G=H$, I no longer need free groups and can relay on the theory of finite direct sums alone.

But, though I'm quite sure there is contradiction, I can't prove it. Can you?

EDIT: I'll change the question. I say (2) is false, but I can't prove this. Can  you? [Actually what the author is asking me to do is exactly to prove the falsity of (2), so I made no real progress above in trying to solve the problem, with the exception of the first proof I gave above.]

Comment: Are you assuming all sets are finite?

Comment: Also, in the third line, how do you conclude from $G\cong H$ that $|X|=|Y|$? That seems like the crux of the entire question.

Comment: Far-reaching generalization for interested readers. Exercise (Jónsson-Tarski): let $\mathcal{V}$ be a variety (of a certain signature) in universal algebra. If there exists a finite model of cardinal $\ge 2$ in $\mathcal{V}$, then for every finite $k\ge 1$ the free object $F_{\mathcal{V},k}$ on $k$ generators in $\mathcal{V}$ cannot be generated by less than $k$ elements.

Comment: Before answering the comments: I'll hardly found a contradiction. $C_6=C_2 \oplus C_3$ where $C_i$ is the cyclic group of order $i$.

Comment: @Servaes: Yes, n is a natural number (I assume it to be).

Comment: @Servaes: I showed H is free abelian on Y.  Then I used a theorem that appears in the book before the problem: if A free abel on X and B free abel on Y and A isomorphic with B then |X|=|Y|. But the chapter is about decomposition of abelian groups into direct sums and I'd like to use properties about them.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why I get H free abelian on Y. For suppose Y is a linearly dependent subset of G. How can H be free abelian on such a subset?

Comment: The thing about decompositions into cyclic group and uniqueness I find it unnecessary. I could begin with this: Say G= Z x Z is generated by an element of G. Then Z x Z isomorphich with Z. But of course, which is then the rank of G? 2 or 1? I don't see why the author put the problem in this chapter when it can be solved with material from the preceding chapter. The book is Derek Robinson, A Course in the theory of Groups, 2nd ed. The problem is 4.2.1.

Comment: What is your definition of a free abelian group? It should be immediate from the definition that any subgroup of a free abelian group is again a free abelian group. Also, it is entirely unclear to me what you are asking; every part of the question comes across as incoherent to me.

Comment: @Servaes I find it hardly obvious that subgroups of free abelian groups are free abelian. It's not a hard result of course, but does not follow directly from the definition.

Comment: @Servaes: the definition I use is: let F be an abelian group and X a subset of F. F is a free group on X if given any abelian group G and a funcion f from X to G there is a homomorphism $\phi$ from F to G that extends f.

Comment: There is only one question in the OP: "Can you?". If by "question" you mean the entire OP then I think I should go to see a shrink. I'll add I edited the OP (see under "EDIT").

Comment: @CaptainLama Fair enough. I had the finitely generated case in mind, as this is what the question is about. In this case it is pretty much immediate, I would say.